# C# FIxing Foreach loop with no values

Tags: c#, sql-server, foreach

I'm trying to execute the following code, where two columns full of game ids in my DB are matched, then three separate queries are executed to pull related information for the game ids that matched, and it's all packaged nicely in an e-mail.

```
foreach (var TempId in ResultGameIDCompare)

var command1 = "EXEC DB query";
var command2 = "EXEC DB query";
var command3 = "EXEC DB query";

var GameInfo = db2.Query(command1, (string)TempId.Game_ID);
var SystemInfo = db2.Query(command2, (string)TempId.Game_ID); 
var EditionInfo = db2.Query(command3, (string)TempId.Game_ID);  

foreach (var result in GameInfo) 
      {

        foreach (var result2 in SystemInfo) 
         {

           foreach (var result3 in EditionInfo) 
             {

                var text = " <ul>"+
                             "<p>My game information is as follows:" +@result.Name+"</p>"+
                             " <strong>System:</strong> "   @result2.System+
                             " <strong>Price:</strong> "  +@result3.Price+
                             " <strong>Edition:</strong> "  +@result3.Edition+
                             "<ul>";

                 WebMail.Send("Test@test.com",
                   "This is a test", 
                   body : text, 
                   isBodyHtml:true );  
               }  
           }
       }
```

The code works but if one of my queries returns an empty row nothing is fed into the collection for that `game id` and understandably no e-mail is generated for that `game id`.

So I'm trying to re-work my code so an e-mail is still generated even if an empty row is returned for the `SystemInfo` or `EditionInfo` query(`GameInfo` will never return an empty row) but I'm having difficulty figuring out how to go about this. I've attempted modifying my code as follows:

```
var Blank = " ";
foreach (var TempId in ResultGameIDCompare)

var command1 = "EXEC DB query";
var command2 = "EXEC DB query";
var command3 = "EXEC DB query";

var GameInfo = db2.Query(command1, (string)TempId.Game_ID);
var SystemInfo = db2.Query(command2, (string)TempId.Game_ID); 
var EditionInfo = db2.Query(command3, (string)TempId.Game_ID);  

foreach (var result in GameInfo) 
      {

        foreach (var result2 in SystemInfo.DefaultIfEmpty(Blank)) 
         {

           foreach (var result3 in EditionInfo.DefaultIfEmpty(Blank)) 
             {

                var text = " <ul>"+
                             "<p>My game information is as follows:" +@result.Name+"</p>"+
                             " <strong>System:</strong> "   @result2.System+
                             " <strong>Price:</strong> "  +@result3.Price+
                             " <strong>Edition:</strong> "  +@result3.Edition+
                             "<ul>";

                 WebMail.Send("Test@test.com",
                   "This is a test", 
                   body : text, 
                   isBodyHtml:true );  
               }  
           }
       }
```

But it returns error `"string' does not contain a definition for 'System'"` and I'm honestly not sure if this alteration will do what I think it will do. Return " " in positions no data was returned from the query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
foreach (var result in GameInfo)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.Append("<ul>");
    sb.AppendFormat("<p>My game information is as follows: {0}</p>", @result.Name);

    foreach (var result2 in SystemInfo)
    {
        sb.AppendFormat("<strong>System: {0}</strong>", @result2.System);

        foreach (var result3 in EditionInfo)
        {
            sb.AppendFormat("<strong>Price: {0}</strong>", @result3.Price);
            sb.AppendFormat("<strong>Edition: {0}</strong>", @result3.Edtion);
        }
    }

    sb.Append("</ul>");
    WebMail.Send("Test@test.com",
      "This is a test",
      body: sb.ToString(),
      isBodyHtml: true);  
}
```

Just move the creation of the string outside into the first loop, and add to it in the inner loops as you get more data. `StringBuilder` is a high performance string concatenation system in the `System.Text` namespace and avoids pricey `+` concatenations.

Comment: While this looks good, it does not solve the OPs perceived problem. You moved the sending block into the outer loop. The OP wants (or at least does, don't know if he really wants) to send a mail per innermost loop iteration.

Comment: +1 for the recommendation of using stringbuilder...This is honestly a better solution, especially if the email itself needs to be fledged out more than a couple lines of plain text.

Comment: @nvoigt Going by this in his post *"So I'm trying to re-work my code so an e-mail is still generated even if an empty row is returned for the SystemInfo or EditionInfo query"* I'm guessing he really does want to send an email per outermost loop.

Comment: There are only ~10 very tiny strings being concatenated, and then an email is immediately being sent.  If @LearningProgrammer were smashing ALL the HTML from EVERY iteration together and sending it in one big email at the end, then yeah, you'd be right to suggest StringBuilder - but as it is, the overhead from instantiating StringBuilder is likely to cancel out the performance benefit, because there just isn't that much data being concatenated.  That, and you're not actually answering the question being asked.

Comment: I'm presuming (maybe incorrectly) that the actual emails that will be used will have more to them than what's actually being shown.  Proof of concept first, pretty up the output later.

Comment: @Diosjenin, if I understand OP right I think this does answer the question.  OP wants an email to be sent even if the SystemInfo or GameInfo collections are empty.  But because OP was sending the email in the inner-most loop, if the collection was empty then ForEach would do nothing and no email would be sent.  By moving the email to the outer-most loop, it will always be sent even if SystemInfo or GameInfo is empty.

Comment: @user2366842 and @Calcolat are correct in their assumptions. I apologize for not making the question clearer but I also didn't want to overload the question. @Ron Beyer, thank you very much. I've been testing out `StringBuilder` function and building off your example and it's exactly what I needed for this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Your variable `Blank` needs to be an `IEnumerable` of the same type as your original collection.

If your `SystemInfo` is a collection of strings,

```
SystemInfo.DefaultIfEmpty(new[]{ Blank })
```

will do.